# Probability of event A or B occuring given 3 events A, B and C

Tags: probability

I am struggling a little bit with Probability.

I am given 3 events after tossing 2 triangular die. ( 4 sides, numbered 1 to 4))

Event A: the bottom faces sum up to 6  (3/16)

Event B: each bottom face shows an even number (4/16)

Event C: each bottom face shows the same number(doubles) (4/16)

I am asked to find P(A U B)

So the formula I was given for Union was P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(B ^ A)..

So I did P(A U B) = (3/16) + (4/16) - (3/16 * 4/16)

BUT this is not the right answer. Do I also have to account for C? I.e

P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(C) -P(A ^ B) - P(A ^ C) - P(B ^ C)

Is this correct? ( I have a limited number of tries on the problem)

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you got as the answer that was incorrect, just how you claim to have computed it.  What if you computed one of the terms incorrectly?  Show your work, and you'll be more likely to get feedback.

Comment: @NickPeterson    I had the probability of A as 3/16, the probability of B as 4/16, and the probability of C as 4/16. My first attempt I did P(A U B) = (3/16) + (4/16) - (3/16 * 4/16)

Comment: Why do you have a limited number of 'tries on the problem'? Is it because you are doing a test/homework where this is one of the problems? Sorry for being blunt. Also, $P(A\cap B)\ne P(A)\cdot P(B)$ in general - that may be your mistake. (It is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.)

Comment: @user8734617 Yes, it's an assignment. Its not due for a while but I am using it to study for an upcoming quiz.

Comment: To be picky, these dice are *tetrahedral*, not triangular.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome space consists of $16$ atoms occuring without bias; the ordered pairs of results for the two, fair tetrahedral-die.

> Event A: the bottom faces sum up to 6 (3/16)

$A=\{(2,4),(3,3),(4,2)\}$ so yes.

> Event B: each bottom face shows an even number (4/16)

$B=\{(2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4)\}$ so yes.

> Event C: each bottom face shows the same number(doubles) (4/16)

$C=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ so yes.

> I am asked to find $P(A \cup B)$

What is the set $A\cup B$?  How many atoms does it hold?  That will immediately tell you the answer.

> So the formula I was given for Union was $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(B \cap A)$..

Well, sure, that is so.   However, what is $A\cap B$?   How many atoms are in this intersection?   That will lead you to the answer.

> So I did $P(A \cup B) = (3/16) + (4/16) - (3/16 * 4/16)$
>
> BUT this is not the right answer.

Indeed it is not.   You are using the product rule for the probability for an intersection of *independent events*.   They are *not* independent.

Comment: The set would be {(2,4), (3,3), (4,2), (4,4), (2,2)}, correct? So in that case P(A U B) would just be 5/16? Am I over complicating this for myself?!! Thanks a lot for the help and detailed answer.